# How do I convert a list of integers into an actual list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a string of integers for ex. `1 2 3 4 5`. How do I convert it into a list like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "something like 1 2 3 4 5"?

Comment: If you have a "list of integers" you already have a list.

Comment: By that I was asking how to convert a "list" of numbers which in this example was 1 2 3 4 5 into an actual list [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. Sorry if that wasn't clear!

Comment: Either way, Sabil answered with what I was looking for.

Comment: A more clear way to describe what you have would be 'the string `"1 2 3 4 5"`'.  There are a lot of things that are "like 1 2 3 4 5" (maybe you mean the tuple `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`?) but if you say you have a *string* it's very clear which one of them you're talking about!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do this:**

```
int_str = '1 2 3 4 5'

int_list = list(map(int, int_str.split()))

print(int_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```